# Regarding generating of HBM files in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I am learning Hibernate , I just want to know is there any plugin in eclipse which generates the Hbm Files hibernate mapping files in XML format automatically. Please Advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can get the jboss tools plugin for eclipse which includes the Hibernate tools.

http://www.jboss.org/tools/download.html